# why can't I remove spaces using tr -s

Tags: command-line, tr

when I enter the following

```
echo "This   is   for    testing" | tr -s [:space:]
```

I get this...

```
This   is   for    testing
```

I was hoping to remove the multiple spaces and just have one space between the words.  I don't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It worked for me. I copied and pasted your exact text into an SSH session on my test 20.04.4 Ubuntu server.

Comment: Is there a file in the current directory with single-character name `:`, `s`, `p`, `a`, `c` or `e`? Does it work with `tr -s '[:space:]'`?

Comment: I tried it. It didnt work. Then I piped it to hexdump. It looks like the chars arent really spaces. Maybe if you copied the command from a web page, they arent spaces. But, I tryed typing it out and it workd as expected

Comment: Omg I never thought to check, they weren't spaces.  Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

In `tr -s [:space:]`, the unquoted `[:space:]` will be treated by the shell as a glob, and if you a file that matches that glob (a filename with a single character of any of `:`, `a`, `c`, `e`, `p`, `s`), then your shell (likely bash) will expand that glob to that filename:

```
bash-5.1$ echo tr -s [:space:]
tr -s [:space:]
bash-5.1$ touch c
bash-5.1$ echo tr -s [:space:]
tr -s c
```

(It might also do other things based on shell options.)

So, use quoting so that the shell doesn't interpret `[:space:]`:

```
echo "This   is   for    testing" | tr -s '[:space:]'
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in squeezing the spaces, maybe it doesn't work for you because those spaces in your sample text aren't really spaces,

They could be tabs

Try this

```
echo "This   is   for   testing" | tr \\t " "
```

or, if there are multiple tabs you can try using

```
echo "This  is   for   testing" | tr \\t " " | tr -s [:space:]
```